# how can crop image using c# windows phone

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

how can crop image using c# windows phone

crop rect from image

how can crop face from image

the code :

```
    BitmapImage bmp = new BitmapImage();
    bmp.SetSource(e.ChosenPhoto);

    imgShow.ImageSource = bmp;
    var wb = new WriteableBitmap(bmp);
    var sdkImg = ImageConverter.SystemToSdk(wb);

    IFaceDetector detector = FaceDetectorFactory.Create(FaceDetectionType.Haar);
    var gray = new ImageGray(sdkImg);
    FaceRect[] rc = detector.Detect(gray);
    MessageBox.Show(rc[0].ToString());

    faceRect.Margin = new Thickness(rc[1].Rect.Left / 2, rc[1].Rect.Top / 2, 0, 0);
    faceRect.Width = rc[1].Rect.Width;
    faceRect.Height = rc[1].Rect.Height;
    faceRect.Visibility = System.Windows.Visibility.Visible;
```

Answer (score 3):

You could simply do it using the `WriteableBitmap` class which is inherited from `BitmapSource`. There are many samples out there, which you could follow.

References:

- [WindowsPhone: Image crop with rectangle](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/WindowsPhone-Image-crop-925bc2c9)
- [Crop Image Area with Different Shapes](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsapps/WindowsPhone-Crop-Image-dc9a81db)
- [Crop an Image using the WriteableBitmap](http://www.kunal-chowdhury.com/2012/12/how-to-crop-image-using-writeablebitmap.html)